# Retain focus after page refresh in JSF 2.0 SUN RI

Tags: jsf-2, focus, accessibility

In my current project we're trying to write an application (using SUN RI JSF 2.0) implementation mainly for accessibility (with JAWS and windows EYE).

Most of the things are up as expected except for the focus after each refresh. On each change in dropdown (combobox), we've to populate another one with dependent values, this causes the whole page to refresh and we loose focus on the last field. The refresh is done using navigation rule back to the same page so that screen readers can get the event and get new values.

Is there a way around this to somehow remember the last focus position and retain the focus so that screen readers can read from that position onwards and not the complete page beginning.

I have searched google and lot of other great stuff written by 'baluc' or other people in this field but can not identify the correct solution to this.

Thanks a lot for your patience in going through it.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for reading guys. I finally used <f:ajax> and somehow JAWS was able to identify the dynamic content so focus was retained and things are moving as expected.

Comment: Make your comment into an answer and then accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used  and somehow JAWS was able to identify the dynamic content so focus was retained and things are moving as expected.